# Getting error when transer file with Openfrie using Smack API

Tags: android, openfire, smack

I want to transfer file eg. image or video from Openfire with Smack Api.
But I am getting an error code  503 service unavailable every time.
**My Coding is**

```
public void  onConnectionEstablished(){
    fileTransferManager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    OutgoingFileTransfer.setResponseTimeout(30000);
    addFileTransferListener();
}


public void sendImage(File file, String to) throws SmackInvocationException {
    if (fileTransferManager == null || !isConnected()) {
        throw new SmackInvocationException("server not connected");
    }

    EntityFullJid fullJid;



    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = fileTransferManager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(getFullJid(to));

    try {

        transfer.sendFile(file, file.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "send file error");
        throw new SmackInvocationException(e);
    }

    while(!transfer.isDone()) {
        if(transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused) || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)
                || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)){
            throw new SmackInvocationException("send file error, " + transfer.getError());
        }
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "send file status: " + transfer.getStatus());
    if(transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused) || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)
            || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)){
        throw new SmackInvocationException("send file error, " + transfer.getError());
    }
}

private void addFileTransferListener() {

    fileTransferManager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
        public void fileTransferRequest(final FileTransferRequest request) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
                    String fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    File file = new File(FileUtils.getReceivedImagesDir(context), fileName + FileUtils.IMAGE_EXTENSION);
                    try {
                        transfer.recieveFile(file);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (SmackException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "receive file error", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    while (!transfer.isDone()) {
                        if(transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused) || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)
                                || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)){
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "receive file error, " + transfer.getError());
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
}
```

**My Log is**

```
<iq type="error" id="Z6hyN-147" from="7665935694@ec2-18-221-73-31.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/smack" to="8094772915@ec2-18-221-73-31.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/smack"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="jsi_1095486335648182993" mime-type="image/jpeg" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"><file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="1509942029217.jpg" size="830807"><desc>1509942029217.jpg</desc></file><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form"><field var="stream-method" type="list-single"><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></option></field></x></feature></si><error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

One thing i observed that when both the user sender and receiver are on the same network then not getting error.

And there is a file transfer setting in Openfire server that is given below.I donot know  what it means and how to configure it.

[image]

I have seen a lot of question on stackoverflow but no answer i got.
Please help me.Thanks

Comment: described in log file

Comment: You think anyone will read that log? Why do you force us to scroll half an hour? Please post in such a way that we do not have to scroll.

Comment: i have edited the question ...pls if you know help me...and also let me know can openfire send the file if reciver is offline

Comment: You were too lazy to format the log?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I investigated the stanza and solved it this way.

Many people use **"/Smack**" or **"/Resource"** as resource part in jid, but that can be done another way.

Resource path is changing with every presence changed of user. Lets say we want to send image to this user:
**"user1@mydomain"**

You must add "/Resource" or "/Smack" part to this jid and it become this:
**user1@mydomain/Resource**

But resource path is changing with presence so you must follow every presence change to update resource path.
Best way is to get user presence is in roster listener and in presencheChanged() method you get last user resource part like this:

```
Roster roster=getRoster();
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
                @Override
                public void entriesAdded(Collection<Jid> addresses) {
                    Log.d("entriesAdded", "ug");
                    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("ENTRIES_ADDED"));
                }

                @Override
                public void entriesUpdated(Collection<Jid> addresses) {
                    Log.d("entriesUpdated", "ug");
                }

                @Override
                public void entriesDeleted(Collection<Jid> addresses) {
                    Log.d("entriesDeleted", "ug");
                }

                @Override
                public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
                    Log.d("presenceChanged", "ug");
                    //Resource from presence
                    String resource = presence.getFrom().getResourceOrEmpty().toString();
                    //Update resource part for user in DB or preferences
                    //...
                }
            });
}
```

Resource string will be some generated string like **"6u1613j3kv**" and jid will become:
**user1@mydomain/6u1613j3kv**

That means that you must create your outgoing transfer like this:

```
EntityFullJid jid = JidCreate.entityFullFrom("user1@mydomain/6u1613j3kv"); 
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(jid)
```

In your case :
    String to = "user1@mydomain/6u1613j3kv";
    EntityFullJid fullJid = JidCreate.entityFullFrom(to);
    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = fileTransferManager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(fullJid);

**6u1613j3kv** string is generated on every presence change.

And that is how i have solved my problem with file transfer on smack and Openfire.

Also to mention you must add following properties in your Openfire server:

```
xmpp.proxy.enabled - true
xmpp.proxy.externalip - MY_IP_ADDRESS
xmpp.proxy.port -7777
```

Just to mention, I am using Openfire 4.0.2 and Smack 4.2.2.